# Controller method doesn't catch object routes from redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm sending data from form to my `Test` method and the data is there,

If some error has occured, then I'm mapping my `ModelInput` to `Model` and then I'm performing an redirect to `MyView` with data sent via Object routes. For some reason in `MyView` param `input` is null, even if `input` in `Test` had correct values

Any idea why after redirect my data (input param) is being lost?

BTW: **Guid? Id is sent correctly**

```
public IActionResult MyView(Guid? id, Model input = null)
{
    // after redirect input is empty
    (...)
}
```

__

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(Guid id, ModelInput user_input)
{
    (...)
    if (error)
    {
        var input = new Model
        {
            FirstName = user_input.FirstName,
            SecondName = user_input.SecondName
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyView), new { id, input });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with passing an object as a route parameter is that the resulting url is built by calling `ToString` for every parameter and instead of `input.FirstName=value&input.SecondName=value` you got `input=YourSolution.Controllers.YourController+Model` which is obviously invalid. In your case the following code will be sufficient to fix the problem

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyView), new { id, input.FirstName, input.SecondName });
```