# Best way to append query string parameter to URL from object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have query string class.

```
  public class PagingModel
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
       
        public string Filter { get; set; } = "text";
    }

string url = "Menu/GetMenus";
```

I have to generate the URI with a query string based on an object in ASP.NET Core 5 preview. Is there any built in query helper?.

Required output:

```
/Menu/GetMenus?PageNumber=3&Filter=text
```

MVC Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> index_partial([FromQuery] PagingModel paging)
            {
              
                var data = await _apiService.GetMenusAsync(paging);
    
                return PartialView("_IndexPartial", data);
            }
```

Service:

```
   public async Task<PagedList<MenuModel>> GetMenusAsync(PagingModel paging)
            {
                string Requiredurl = "Menu/GetMenus?page="+ paging.PageNumber;
               
            }
```

Comment: I'd write my own small helper and use `WebUtility` to encode filter value. S. a. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920875/url-encode-and-decode-in-asp-net-core

Comment: is this MVC? if so could you show the controller?

Comment: I have controller in MVC that accepts complex query string in that I am calling api ...so I want to append query string object to call api controller

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531257/controller-method-doesnt-catch-object-routes-from-redirect/54531531#54531531)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen No need to reinvent the wheel: [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-url/) has URL building built in.

Comment: @mason - cool lib. I don't like that it adds extension methods to string class and I'd argue that in this case a custom method would be much easier to use and less error prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this extension method.. No need to generate query string manually.Only class object we need to pass. i thought some one else  can use the same thing ...

```
public static string AppendObjectToQueryString(string uri, object requestObject)
        {
            var type = requestObject.GetType();
            var data = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .ToDictionary
                (
                    p => p.Name,
                    p => p.GetValue(requestObject)
                );

            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                if (d.Value == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if ((d.Value as string == null) && d.Value is IEnumerable enumerable)
                {
                    foreach (var value in enumerable)
                    {
                        uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, d.Key, value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, d.Key, d.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            return uri;
        }
```

Ex: In my case i called this way.

```
string uri = "Menu/GetMenus";
 string full_uri = QueryStringExtension.AppendObjectToQueryString(uri, paging);
```

Answer (score 2):

With a Query String this simple I would just do

```
PagingModel qsData = new PagingModel();

//set qsData properties as needed 

string urlWithQueryString = $"/Menu/GetMenus?{nameof(PagingModel.PageNumber)}={qsData.PageNumber}&nameof(PagingModel.Filter)}={qsData.Filter}";
```

However more standard is to do something like

```
string urlWithQueryString = this.Url.Action("GetMenus", "Menu", new PagingModel { PageNumber = 3, Filter = "text" }, this.Request.Url.Scheme);
```

But best solution depends on your specific case - can you add your action method definition for GetMenus ?

Update for your additional code :

Seeing as looks like you want to generate the url inside the service I would simply do this :

```
  public async Task<PagedList<MenuModel>> GetMenusAsync(PagingModel paging)
            {
                string Requiredurl =  $"/Menu/GetMenus?{nameof(PagingModel.PageNumber)}={paging.PageNumber}&nameof(PagingModel.Filter)}={paging.Filter}";

            }
```

Comment: Thank you .. i have added controller method